# How to get an object to fall/move at constant velocity in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, shapes

I'm a beginner at coding who is trying to make a simple game using javafx. At the moment, I'm trying to get a rectangle to fall down the screen at a constant speed. I tried using getLayoutY() which worked in a EventHandler method where I had to press down an arrow, but I want the object to fall/move without user input. The resources that I search up mainly involve sprite animation which is a bit too complicated for me to understand.
This is the rectangle:

```
    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle();                 
    rect2.setX(500);
    rect2.setY(500);
    rect2.setWidth(100);
    rect2.setHeight(100);
    rect2.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    scene.getChildren().addAll(rect2);
```

This code worked only in a scene.setOnKeyPressed()... method

```
    rect2.setLayoutY(rect2.getLayoutY() + 10);
```

Comment: Read up on the [Animation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/animations.htm#JFXTE149), particularly [`TranslateTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html). For (much) more advanced animation techniques, see http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx.html (which relies on http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think transitions is what you need: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm

I your case (not tested):

```
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle();                 
rect2.setX(500);
rect2.setY(500);
rect2.setWidth(100);
rect2.setHeight(100);
rect2.setFill(Color.BLUE);
scene.getChildren().addAll(rect2);
Path path = new Path();
path.getElements().add (new MoveTo (0, 0));
path.getElements().add (new LineTo(0, 100));

PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(10000));
pathTransition.setNode(cbTypeCrc);
pathTransition.setPath(path);
pathTransition.setOrientation(OrientationType.NONE);
pathTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
pathTransition.play();
```

Comment: It's probably easier with a `TranslateTransition`, since the path is just a straight line. For reference, a more up to date version of the documentation you linked is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/animations.htm#JFXTE149